# Open a webpage url on same window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to append drop down values to a html menu using a jQuery append function. I would like to open a web page URL once I load the last drop down option. (user selection)

HTML code:

```
<select id="sel_bank" name="sel_bak">
<option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Select Your product</option>
<option>Mobile</option>
<option>laptop</option>
</select>
    
<select id="sel_state" name="sel_state">
<option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Select Your brand</option>
</select>
    
<select id="sel_district" name="sel_district" >
<option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Goto the web</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#sel_bank").change(function() {
 var el = $(this) ;
 if(el.val() === "Mobile" ) {
    $("#sel_state").empty().append
    ("<option SELECTED>Select Your product</option>\
     <option>Samsung</option>\
<option>Nokia</option>");
    }
      else if(el.val() === "laptop" ) {
         $("#sel_state").empty().append
         
          ("<option SELECTED>Select Your product</option>\
     <option>HP</option>\
<option>Dell</option>");
      
      }
  });
     
   $("#sel_state").change(function() {   
       var el = $(this) ;
 if(el.val() === "Samsung" ) {
     
      $("#sel_district").empty().append
    ("<option SELECTED>Goto the web</option>\
  <option>Samsung Web</option>");
     
}
       
if(el.val() === "Nokia" ) {
     
      $("#sel_district").empty().append
    ("<option SELECTED>Goto the web</option>\
  <option>Nokia Web</option>");
     
}
       
         });
     
        $("#sel_state").change(function() {   
       var el = $(this) ;
 if(el.val() === "HP" ) {
     
      $("#sel_district").empty().append
    ("<option SELECTED>Goto the web</option>\
  <option>HP Web</option>");
     
}
       
if(el.val() === "Dell" ) {
     
      $("#sel_district").empty().append
    ("<option SELECTED>Goto the web</option>\
  <option>Dell Web</option>");
     
}
       
         });

     
  
});
```

When ever select the final drop down options (It may be either one from this: Samsung web, Nokia web, HP web and Dell Web), I would like to open their website.
ie, if I select, Samsung Web, I need to open Samsung webpage? How can I do that? I have tried with

```
     $("#sel_district").change(function() {   
       var el = $(this) ;
 if(el.val() === "Samsung Web" ) { 
   window.location.href = "www.samsung.com";

}
```

But, instead of opening, `www.samsung.com`, it is opening like `file:///C:/Users/aratnan/Desktop/www.samsung.com`

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/anoopcr/wd46s/1/)**

Comment: Try with adding http:// on the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
window.location.href = "http://www.samsung.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

try `window.location = "http://www.samsung.com"` - see example http://jsfiddle.net/wd46s/2/

Answer (score 0):

Everything you pass to href, without any protocol(like `http`) will search it in your current server location. Adding the `http://` will know that is a external link